# Pass params for other method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

When I make a search, my url result is:

```
/refinanciamentos/index?utf8=✓&pesquisa_func_cpf=**111.111.111-11**&pesquisa_func_matricula=&commit=Pesquisar
```

And after that show all search results, I click on button:

```
<%= link_to 'Reserva', refinanciamentos_reserva_refinanciamento_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

And this button go to other view and other method.
How make for pass the search params (pesquisa_func_cpf=111.111.111-11) for other method in same controller?
The method for search is index and I need pass the params for method reserva_refinanciamento, how make? I don't have no one idea about this =/

**---------------------**
**UDPDATE:**
This is my controller

```
      def index
        if params[:pesquisa_func_cpf].present?
          @funcionarios = Funcionario.pesquisa_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).all
          @autorizacoes = Autorizacao.pesquisa_func_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]).all
(...)


  def reserva_refinanciamento
   # nothing here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<%= link_to 'Reserva', refinanciamentos_reserva_refinanciamento_path(:pesquisa_func_cpf => params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Then in **reserva_refinanciamento** method you can able to get the search data by **params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]**.

Comment: But the method reserva_refinanciamento don't search. This method is response for save on form the datas and the params on search will just show on view in this same method

Comment: you mean after save want to pass the search params to other method/action ?

Comment: Example... I have a method index = my seach, this method pass params for method reserva_refinanciamento, and this method receive the params and show on view and register on forms

Comment: can you please add you controller here ?

Comment: in method reserva_refinanciamento I put this: @funcionario = Funcionario.pesquisa_cpf(params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]) and my view this: <%= @funcionario.pessoa.nome %> but dont work. Get this error undefined method `pessoa' for

Comment: then above answer will work because refinanciamentos_reserva_refinanciamento_path(:pesquisa_func_cpf => params[:pesquisa_func_cpf]) pass the params to  reserva_refinanciamento method